# Duplicate key exception when adding a user to a group

Tags: keycloak

I've written an EventListenerProvider designed to automatically add a new user to a group after the user completes registration.  The EventListenerProvider looks for the REGISTER event and invokes some code that gets the UserModel:

```
UserModel user = session.getContext().getAuthenticationSession().getAuthenticatedUser();
```

the group is created if it doesn't exist:

```
group = session.getContext().getRealm().createGroup(groupName);
```

and then the user is added to the group:

```
user.joinGroup(group);
```

The problem is that for some reason, `joinGroup` results in an INSERT on the user_entity table using the same id as the user that was supposedly created during registration. This results in a unique key violation with the following partial stack trace:

```
keycloak_1  | 22:44:17,992 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
keycloak_1  | 22:44:17,992 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_fb"
keycloak_1  |   Detail: Key (id)=(3e707ca2-6311-4d0b-bd56-786746b172f0) already exists.
keycloak_1  | 22:44:17,993 ERROR [org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder] (default task-1) Failed to send type to com.abinitio.sso.keycloak.event.EventListener@4d6c5c44: org.keycloak.models.ModelDuplicateException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.convert(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:57)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.invoke(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:51)
keycloak_1  |   at javax.persistence.api@2.2.3//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.flush(Unknown Source)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.models.jpa.UserAdapter.joinGroupImpl(UserAdapter.java:389)
```

The Postgres log shows the following:

```
postgres_1  | 2020-05-20 22:44:17.991 UTC [34] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "constraint_fb"
postgres_1  | 2020-05-20 22:44:17.991 UTC [34] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3e707ca2-6311-4d0b-bd56-786746b172f0) already exists.
postgres_1  | 2020-05-20 22:44:17.991 UTC [34] STATEMENT:  insert into public.USER_ENTITY (CREATED_TIMESTAMP, EMAIL, EMAIL_CONSTRAINT, EMAIL_VERIFIED, ENABLED, FEDERATION_LINK, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, NOT_BEFORE, REALM_ID, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK, USERNAME, ID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13)
```

I'm not quite sure why the `joinGroup` call results in an INSERT on the user_entity table.

After this error, the user that was registering is **not** in the DB.  So I'm assuming the user create resulting from registration was never committed. Perhaps this was still pending which is why the INSERT on the user_entity table happens when `joinGroup` tried to commit?  I tried calling `EntityManager.flush()` just prior to call `joinGroup()`, but this didn't solve the problem.

Hopeful for some suggestions...